# It is possible to reproduce the Windows 8 Fast Hybrid Boot into Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, performance, windows-8, hybrid-boot

One of the best new features introduced by Microsoft in Windows 8 is the [Fast Hybrid Boot](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152937-what-is-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8-and-how-does-it-work/), which improves Windows 8 boot times up to 70% compared to Windows 7:

[image]

Basically, what this new technique does is resume a hibernation file that was saved from Windows' previous boot. Based on the fact this hibernation file already exists on Windows 7, could the same technique be used on a Windows 7 system? How could I do such thing?

Comment: Hibernate is technically still faster than Fast Hybrid Boot, so you can use that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Windows 8 Build Blog](http://windows8build.com/2011/10/windows-8-hybrid-boot-enable-or-disable/):

> The new Windows 8 Hybrid Boot is fast because of the new feature
>   called Hybrid boot. Generally in hibernation mode, all files are saved
>   in the same state, but in Windows 8 Hybrid Boot mode only the system
>   files are saved, so that booting will not take much time.

This can't be reproduced in Windows 7 without modifying the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use hibernate instead.

Win8 hybrid boot is combination between hibernate and shutdown

Logoff and hibernate from logon. Thats like Hybrid boot.